# Expressions from News headlines

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

I'm trying to know which of these expressions is/are correct:

- Kidnapped victims
- Abducted victims
- kidnap victims

Note: I have noticed that most news blogs and websites for some weird reasons, prefer the use of the expression "kidnap victims" and it's so odd to me.

I understand that what should follow the word "victims" is an adjective and the word "kidnap" is not one.

On my part, I do favour the use of the first two expressions;

kidnapped victims and abducted victims cos "kidnapped" and "abducted" are both adjectives.

Comment: "Kidnap" is a noun modifying the noun "victim", describing the type of victim. This is very common in English, e.g. "sugar bowl", "paper company". I think there are already a lot of questions about this issue, but perhaps not easy to find.

Comment: As @StuartFsays, _kidnap victim_ is normal English. But iIn addition, headlines are often written in [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese), using constructions which are ungrammatical or unidiomatic in normal English, so it is not a good idea to look to them for how English works.

Comment: Certainly don't look to *newspaper headlines* for the finer points of English grammar! They might go with ***abducted** victims* simply because it saves one letter over the idiomatically established ***noun adjunct*** usages for such contexts (noun ***victim*** modified by nouns ***abduction, kidnap***).